# How to create multiple charts of same type but with different dataseries using JRBeanCollectionDatasource in Jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to create multiple XY-line charts with different dataset using same chart report template and I also have to use JRBeanCollectionDatasource for it.

**Requirements:**

1) Should be done using JRBeanCollectionDatasource.

2) Have to use the same chart report template to create multiple charts.

3) Number of charts are not fixed (Here I have problem giving names to Report Parameter in java). Because in ReportParametersMap, they can only have unique key name .

**Java:**

Coordinates.java

```
private Number series;
private Number xCoordinate;
private Number yCoordinate;
//Getters & Setters
```

GenerateReport.java

I am working with Report Book and each report template of the report book is considered as a sub-report. So I am passing `XYChartDataSource`(java.util.List) to master report book and I would map this parameter with the subreport by using 
  `new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{XYChartDataSource})` as a Datasource Expression.

and in Subreport, I have created a parameter `XYChartDataSource`(java.util.List) and created fields (series,xCoordinate,yCoordinate) in MainDataset ( used in chart)

```
List<List<Coordinates>> allchartData = new ArrayList<>();
List<Coordinates> chartData = new ArrayList<>();

chartData.add(new Coordinates(2.08, xCoordinate, yCoordinate));
chartData.add(new Coordinates(2.08, xCoordinate, yCoordinate));
chartData.add(new Coordinates(2.08, xCoordinate, yCoordinate));
allchartData.add(chartData);
.
.
.
chartData.add(new Coordinates(2.12, xCoordinate, yCoordinate));
chartData.add(new Coordinates(2.12, xCoordinate, yCoordinate));
chartData.add(new Coordinates(2.12, xCoordinate, yCoordinate));
allchartData.add(chartData);
.
.
.


for (int i = 0; i < baselineChartData.size(); i++) {
            parameters.put("XYChartDataSource", allchartData.get(i));
    }
```

**main_report_book.jrxml**

```
<parameter name="XYChartDataSource" class="java.util.List"/>

        <part uuid="5e668430-9acd-4835-be21-f4e2902ce33d">
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{XYChartDataSource})]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/sub_chart.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
```

**sub_chart.jrxml**

```
<parameter name="XYChartDataSource" class="java.util.List"/>
<field name="xCoordinate" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="yCoordinate" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="series" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="405">
            <xyLineChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report" bookmarkLevel="1">
                    <reportElement x="30" y="98" width="525" height="230" uuid="627d87d6-b675-409c-accb-b2bb3ffb9c80">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.domain.axis.tick.interval" value="1"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend position="Right"/>
                </chart>
                <xyDataset>
                    <xySeries autoSort="true">
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{series}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <xValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{xCoordinate}]]></xValueExpression>
                        <yValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{yCoordinate}]]></yValueExpression>

                    </xySeries>
                </xyDataset>
                <linePlot isShowShapes="false">
                    <plot/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </linePlot>
            </xyLineChart>






            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
```

**Current Output:**
only one chart is being printed, using the regular method.

[image]

**Expected Output:**

Here I am showing two charts(could be more in actual output) , which needs to be generated from same report template in the SAME PDF REPORT:

> chart1

[image]

> chart2

[image]

Comment: I did a rollback since the problem in your edit was related to something you changed from this original question (hence question is more clear for future users like this), I have added your great graphical representation to the answer with attribution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < baselineChartData.size(); i++) {
        parameters.put("XYChartDataSource", allchartData.get(i));
}
```

Your parameter `"XYChartDataSource"` will contain last entry in your `List`, you replace each time in loop see [Map.put(K key,V value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-))

What we need instead is the **whole list**

```
parameters.put("XYChartDataSource", allchartData);
```

However now we can't access directly the `List<Coordinates>`

On solution to not change your current subreport is to insert another subreport in the middle which will iterate your `List<List<Coordinates>>` in detail band.

The structure will be

1. Pass `List<List<Coordinates>> allchartData` as datasource to this new subreport (sub_charts.jrxml)
2. Define the field `_THIS` which is `List<Coordinates>` in subreport (hence it's iterating your `List<List<Coordinates>>`)
3. In detail band include current sub_chart.jrxml and pass `$F{_THIS}` as datasource

**sub_charts.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sub_charts" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bc8c76ba-0b85-4522-bf67-4c62ae87202b">
    <field name="_THIS" class="java.util.List">
        <fieldDescription>_THIS</fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="63" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="550" height="60" uuid="b0e761bf-fe02-4a0a-bafb-32d6831b7a13"/>
                 <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{_THIS})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                 <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/sub_chart.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Remember to call this new subreport in your **main_report_book.jrxml**.

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"/sub_charts.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

The OP [Dhruvil Thaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2147560/dhruvil-thaker) did this great graphical representation of this answer.

[image: graphical representation]

Comment: @DhruvilThaker You have `chartData = new ArrayList<>();`  after you add it to `allChartData`?? hence you need to create new `List` for every chart you like, in doubts show some more code on how you create the data (edit the post)

Comment: @PeterFriberg when I was testing some other options, I kept chart in detail  band and because of that it was repeating for no. of Coordinates object times.

For your answer just correct one thing 

datasource expression for sub_charts.jrxml in main_report_book  will be **new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{XYDatasource})** instead of **XYDatasource<java.util.List>**

Comment: Just a quick question,How will **_THIS** will work  in a scenario where there are more than one type of List?(in this scenario it was just List<List<Coordinates>>, what if I have one more list  List<List<tableData>>?).

Comment: @DhruvilThaker If you are passing a JRBeanCollectionDataSource(List), it will always represent the object that is in that List, whatever it is (a Bean, a List, a Map, a Map with List etc)

Comment: @DhruvilThaker I could not really understand your previous comment dataset passed in main_report_book in question is JRBeanCollectionDataSource(‌​$P{XYDatasource})

Comment: I meant to point out one small mistake in your answer.
(point 1) **Pass List<List<Coordinates>> allchartData as datasource to this new subreport (sub_charts.jrxml)** . So here is the correction :   "new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(‌​$P{XYDatasource})" should be passed.

Comment: could you recommend some documentation for "_THIS", I have a scenario where I need to pass two different types of list into same subreport For Example. A report containing chart and table, for both of them I need to pass a data list. To make my requirement a bit more clear, assume in above example I have to create a chart and a table in "sub_chart.jrxml". is there any option like _THIS.getList1() and _THIS.getList2() ?

Comment: @DhruvilThaker here are some docs http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/, yes you can do like that if you Bean has those two methods.