# Application hanging when generating multiple charts using JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate multiple charts using the approach described here:
[How to create multiple charts of same type but with different dataseries using JRBeanCollectionDatasource in Jasperreports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465301/how-to-create-multiple-charts-of-same-type-but-with-different-dataseries-using-j)

I need to generate multiple charts in a report given a `List<List<ChartBean<Double,Double>>`
which is populated with the data I get from a file.

ChartBean is declared as follows:

```
public class ChartBean<T,U> {
    T xCoordinate;
    U yCoordinate;
    String series;

    public ChartBean(T x,U y,String series) {
        this.xCoordinate = x;
        this.yCoordinate = y;
        this.series = series;
    }

    public void setxCoordinate(T x) {
        this.xCoordinate = x;
    }

    public void setyCoordinate(U y) {
        this.yCoordinate = y;
    }

    public T getxCoordinate() {
        return xCoordinate;
    }

    public U getyCoordinate() {
        return yCoordinate;
    }

    public String setseries() {
        return series;
    }

    public String getseries() {
        return series; 
    }
}
```

I pass the parameters to the template generator in the following way
`parameters.put("XYDataSource", values);` , where values contains the list of list of coordinates.

What I get is that my application hangs and does not generate any report. I checked multiple times the content of the XML and it seems in line with what is described in the post. I tried also to generate one chart (without using list of lists) and it works.

I have a top report whose summary band contains a sub report "sub_charts.xml".
In its detail band I put another subreport which contains the line chart and I use the "_THIS" field to pass the `List<ChartBean<Double,Double>`
The content of the subreports is reported here.

**sub_charts.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subcharts_2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="97e07501-37b1-4c04-970b-33f120c8264d">
<parameter name="REPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="_THIS" class="java.util.List">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<detail>
    <band height="359">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="22" y="25" width="510" height="320" uuid="6ea2325b-969e-472a-9d49-d5c33667fab5"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{_THIS})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DIR}+"/sub_chart.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
```

**sub_chart.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subchart_2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6cdd6eb2-73da-4026-823b-574910e37c68">
<field name="series" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="xCoordinate" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="yCoordinate" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<summary>
    <band height="270">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
        <xyLineChart>
            <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="270" uuid="4bfd2379-7617-47fb-9c2a-4eeb0b72eadf"/>
                <chartTitle/>
                <chartSubtitle/>
                <chartLegend/>
            </chart>
            <xyDataset>
                <xySeries autoSort="true">
                    <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{series}]]></seriesExpression>
                    <xValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{xCoordinate}]]></xValueExpression>
                    <yValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{yCoordinate}]]></yValueExpression>
                </xySeries>
            </xyDataset>
            <linePlot>
                <plot/>
                <categoryAxisFormat>
                    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                </categoryAxisFormat>
                <valueAxisFormat>
                    <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                </valueAxisFormat>
            </linePlot>
        </xyLineChart>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Comment: `What I get is that my application hangs and does not generate any report.` - Did you try to debug?

Comment: I tried to debug in many ways. I checked that the lists are iterated correctly in the subreports. I also tried to put a text field in the subchart which prints out the coordinates. In this case I can see in the report all the coordinates of my plots. The issue happens when I add the chart object and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.